# Why am I not seeing voice typing option in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, firefox

I am running Firefox 76.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 10. I am asked to prepare a document on Google Docs and they are suggesting using voice typing from "Tools" menu of Google Docs, but I can't find such an option in the "Tools" menu.

[image: A screenshot of the "Tools" menu not showing voice typing]

Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google stated that **the voice typing feature is only available on Google Chrome**.

From [Docs Editor Help - Type with your voice](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/4492226),

> ## Type with your voice
>
> You can type and edit by speaking in Google Docs or in Google Slides speaker notes.
>
> **Note**: This feature is only available in Chrome browsers.

Comment: Hmm. I checked on Chromium, it's there :) Btw, useragent trick on Firefox doesn't work in this case!  Haha